# Django - What CBV should I use for my case?

Tags: django, django-views, view

First of all, I want to say that I'm really a novice with Django, and looking for some architectural advice for my project.

I have a front-end template that looks like this:
[image]

When a user clicked "save" button, data in the input fields needs to be saved into a database. The users will be constantly updating these input fields with new values, and there will be a case where none of these data is present in the database, because the user hasn't filled them out yet. The problem is, I am not sure what view method to use.

**views.py**

```
class BhaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.bha
    fields = '__all__'
    context_object_name = 'bha'
    template_name = 'base/bha.html'
```

This just a really rough code that I made just ask a question here. 
I'm aware that there are many kind of class-based-views, such as DetailView, ListView, CreateView, UpdateView... and many more. Which one, or ones should I use for my purpose? I'm thinking that I need some combination of CreateView and UpdateView, since the users will be updating new information to BHA section, but there still are chances that information was not inserted in the first place at all.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you should have both a `CreateView` and an `UpdateView`.

So if the user initially wants to create a BHA by clicking the link `Add new BHA` he should be directed to a url `yourDomain.com/bha/create` that will be handled by a `CreateView`. When he saves that he should be re-directed to another url `yourDomain.com/bha/1/edit` that will be handled by an `UpdateView` where the `1` in the url is the primary key of the newly created database entry. Updates to that instance can only be made through that url.

Both views can usually use about the same template but the `UpdateView` will initially fill the form with data from the model instance identified by the id in the url.

So your url config could look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^bha/', include([
        url(r'^create/$', BHACreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', BHAUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    ], namespace='bha')),

    # other urls ...
]
```

Comment: One complication is that, when the user enters the BHA page, there is always at least one BHA present, even if its fields are all empty. By default, it has at least one BHA. "Add new BHA" is just to add an additional BHA. That's why I was confused how to use update view and create view. How would you recommend to do in this case?

Comment: @EricKim See [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) in the django docs. If you want to reverse the url using `reverse()` or the `url` template tag this will be the namespace for every url inside that include. E.g. if you want to have the url for the create view you could do: `reverse('bha:create')` where `bha` is the namespace.

Comment: sorry I accidentally deleted the namespace question, but Thanks!

Comment: @EricKim In that case you could have another url `yourDomain.com/bha` that is a `RedirectView` that redirects to the create view if no BHA exists yet or to the update view of the bha the user should see by default.